# Kinetic energy cut-off for Gaussian-type orbitals when applying periodic boundary conditions

Tags: density-functional-theory, cp2k, orbitals, periodic-boundary-conditions, abinit

I have a solid with PBC (periodic boundary conditions) and I want to perform a DFT simulation. I use GTO as the basis. In a [paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ct800329m) I read, I can transform the GTO to a Bloch function (crystalline Gaussian-type AOs):

[image]

In the equation $\vec{k}$ denotes the reciprocal lattice vector and $\chi_{\nu}^{GTO}$ is the $A$-th Gaussian-type orbital which center is displaced from the unit cell at $\vec{T}$ by $\vec{r}_A$.

In the input file (whether using CP2K, ABINIT, or something else) I can set a cut-off value for the kinetic energy. But what does the value mean in such a case? What does the formula look like?

For example in CP2K:

```
&MGRID
  NGRIDS 5
  CUTOFF 500
  REL_CUTOFF 60
&END MGRID
```

I know in the case with plane waves as basic functions it would be
$$\tag{2}\frac{\vec{k}+\vec{G}}{2}<E_{cut},$$
where $\vec{G}$ is the vector of the reciprocal lattice. Is it correct to transform the lattice vector $\vec{T}$ of the real space as in Eq. 3 below:

$$G_i=2\pi \frac{T_j\times T_k}{T_i\cdot(T_j\times T_k)}.\tag{3}$$

and then plug it into the formula?

Comment: +1 but please make note of the edits I made just now so that others don't have to do such edits in the future!

Comment: Ohh sorry, I wanted to correctmy bad english :-(.I was too quick with submitting the question.

Comment: I was talking about the equation numbering, tagging, and other things, not just the English :)

Comment: Thank you for the correction! :) I will do it better next time

Comment: The kinetic energy cutoff is just a solely due to using plane waves rather than PBC. For a calculation with crystalline GTOs, you shouldn't need to set a cutoff at all.

Comment: Thank you @Tyberius

Comment: Suslik: Did [this thread](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6140/5) answer your question? If not, please let us know and we can re-open the question (perhaps after adjusting it a bit).

Comment: @NikeDattani Thanks a lot you for your notification. The answer explained my question.